# Add 'Test Packages' folder in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've created a new Netbeans project and noticed that unlike my previous project it's mising the 'Test Packages' folder. This might seem like an easy question, but how can I add this folder?

Here is a screenshot of my 'Projects' window:

[image]

Comment: what type project did you create?  Library, application, ... ?

Comment: I double checked, the type is 'Java application' (the default option that comes up when creating a new project)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming it's a Java project:

> 1. **Create a new folder:** right click the project under "Projects" tab,
>      go to "New" --> "Other.." --> "Other" --> "Folder"
> 2. **Edit project properties:** right click on the project, this time
>      select "Properties"
> 3. Under "Project Properties" select category "Sources"
> 4. Notice the section "Test Package Folders" --> click "Add Folder"

Answer (score 12):

Right click on `Source Packages`, select `New > JUnit Test...`.  Follow the wizard to create the unit test.  The `Test Packages` folder will be created automatically and your unit test will be placed inside.  (Verified in NetBeans 8.)

Comment: This is the fastest way, I didn't even have to actually create the test for the folder to be shown.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a folder called "**test**" in the root (Project) folder and reload the project by right clicking on the project. This worked for me.